# Why is the replacement not happening when using the Search and Replace Scanner module?

Tags: 7, database, drush, search

I am using [Search and Replace Scanner](https://www.drupal.org/project/scanner) module to perform replacement of links in my website. When I run this module, It says replacement successful  and 250 fields are replaced. My site includes English and Dutch as well.But when I see in the database its not at all reflecting, No changes in the links. I referred [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1668686) but no success. Give some other suggestions to achieve this.

I tried [Drush Search & replace](https://www.drupal.org/project/sar), it works awesome, but I dont want to replace all the links, only body content links should get replace. This filtering option is not there in `Drush Search and Replace`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's s bug report for drush. Please report it to or continue discussing in drush's issue queue

Comment: IMO this is **not** about a **drush** bug ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scenario sounds similar to what is described in [issue # 2616640](https://www.drupal.org/node/2616640).

Have a look at [Comment nr 6](https://www.drupal.org/node/2616640#comment-10765602) in it for an explanation for what may be causing it, i.e.:

> It looks like the module assumes that the field content to replace is set to the same language as the node.

Probably your best bet is to try the [patch attached to Comment nr 18](https://www.drupal.org/node/2616640#comment-11103617).

Comment: ***Dankjewel*** for the accept ... though I'm not sure how to interpret your prior comment, can you elaborate a bit on it?

Comment: From yesterday I was facing this issue, but didn't got any solutions. Is this the one u are asking or something else..

Comment: So you mean that by using what you found in the issue I mentioned you got it resolved?

Comment: Yes exactly.. Your suggestion helped me to solve this issue

Comment: @ Pierre.Vriens, Is there any drush commands are there to execute this module through drush?

Comment: @Suraj : not that I'm aware of. And looking at the module source code, I don't see anything like that either. The closest would be the [Drush search & replace](https://www.drupal.org/project/sar) module (which you already mentioned in your question).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44189/discussion-between-suraj-and-pierre-vriens).